# Editing a topic on ASP.NET storefront site

Tags: asp.net, aspdotnetstorefront

I am trying to edit a topic to adjust content on an ASP.NET storefront site and I am not sure where to locate the topic on my server.

I have the ID and TopicName - any suggestion on how to locate?

Thank you.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVHPT.jpg)

I have accessed my server and I am just not sure where to find the topic referenced.

Comment: Why are you still using WebForms in 2023?

Comment: I am working for a client who built this site in 2016

Comment: ...even in 2016 WebForms was already 8 years out-of-date. Yikes.